# What's the best way to implement an application specific script language

Tags: scripting, text-files, desktop-application

I've seen a few programs having an interface like mentioned above.
They have a GUI but you control them with one or multiple scripts (like NASTRAN).
I don't know the exact name for this behaviour.
Assuming I want my Application to "eat" script like this:

```
Control_Solver
    f1=10Hz
    f2=100Hz
    NumFrequencies=20
    Abscissa=lin
    MeshFrequency=200Hz
```

Are there any libraries I can use?
The language is not fixed, C++ preferred, but quasi every language possible.

Comment: Languages like lua and tcl were designed to be embedded into applications.

Comment: You Probably misunderstood me: The script the program reads shall look like the sample above.

Comment: Yes, and you can define your domain specific language with a scripting language like lua or tcl.

Comment: So show me how to do this like mentioned above, afaik you will always need something like braces.